# How to make HTML page fits the screen?

Tags: html, css

I'm designing a web page using html with css, i made a div that contains all the page and consists of the other divs(as usual), but when running the page it's height is like 150% of the browser height :

[image]

and the div that contains all the page:

```
#items {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

and the html code :

```
<div id="items">
<select id="heap" class="basic-example"></select>
<img src="img/bg.png" class="responsive-image">

<div id="dummy"></div>

<div id="gallery">

</div>

  <span id="order_list">
  <img src="img/ItemList.png" class="responsive-image">
<div id="confirm" class="buttonClass">
  <div align="center">Confirm</div>
</div>    

<div id="total" class="totalClass">
  <div align="center"></div>
</div>  
  </span>

</div>
```

Comment: Set html,body{width:100%;height:100%;margin:0;padding:0} and test it.

Comment: With only this block of css and only that part of html, it is quite impossible to understand what makes your page bigger than wanted. Can you provide a live demo ?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle demo?  Maybe adding box-sizing:border-box; will help.

Comment: @DanGoodspeed here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/encz4/) of my code

Comment: @MilchePatern [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/encz4)

Comment: @MbRostami didn't give my the desired result after assigning that, you can take a look at the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/encz4) of my code

Comment: If I add a border:1px solid; to #items, it takes up the full height of the screen.  I guess I'm still not sure what the issue is.

Comment: @DanGoodspeed i added a border but still the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your problem :

You have inner containers positioned lower than 0 but with 100% height. What you see overfloding under is 35px from your position top:35px.

```
#items {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    /*height: 100%;*/ /* removed */
    bottom:0; /* added */
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
#gallery {
    position: absolute;
    width: 75%;
    /*height: 100%;*/ /* removed */
    bottom:0; /* added */
    z-index: 1;
    top: 35px;
}
#order_list {
    position: absolute;
    width: 25%;
    /*height: 100%;*/ /* removed */
    bottom:0; /* added */
    z-index: 2;
    left: 75%;
    top: 35px;
    color: #F33;
    background:url(img/ItemList.png) display: inline-block;
    alignment-adjust: central;
    font: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-size-adjust: inherit;
    grid-rows: inherit;
    list-style: upper-alpha;
    word-spacing: inherit;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    vertical-align: central;
}
```

[You jsfiddle with height:100%; removed and bottom:0; added](http://jsfiddle.net/encz4/1/)

Comment: Ho, i see you wanted more than just a 'this is your problem, here's how to fix it' answer. I wrote my answer to conform with the code you provided. You know now your situation is caused by absolute positioned elements lower than top:0. You just have to inspect the rest of your css and will be able to finish the job. Don't you?

Comment: Here, i updated your jsfiddle with what i explained in my answer.